# Skyrim Follower More Than One

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Using Console command `set playerfollowercount to 0` my old follower leaves. Only Serana doesn't leave and I need one more than Lydia. I know there are hundreds of mods which can fix this but My friend don't want to use them

Comment: @ryan I  know there are hundreds of mods which can fix this but My friend don't want to use mod for his game any npc command would be helpful thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, If this is the case you could always try using a mod that would increase the amount of followers, then you wouldn't have an issue try [this](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/36132//?). This is usually a glitch caused by starting a quest where a npc waits for you. I myself have had this glitch and I just used an older save to before this had happened.